why can a t test not be used if a single data set is available as a null hypothesis?
I have a data set in which I want to compare whether there is a change. However, my null hypothesis is based on only one data point. But why can't I get this one data point to be recognised as the average, which I can use to determine the t test?

I think you're asking about a two-sample test with only one observation in one of the samples. If not, please edit your question to clarify

I agree, your question is unclear; in particular your title talks about "a single data set" but your body text about "a data point". Further, it's not at all clear why you are conflating a null hypothesis with a data set - hypotheses (null and alternative) are normally statements about population parameters. If you don't feel the linked question and answer is relevant, you will need to edit your question to clarify the situation, preferably in simple, non-technical terms (i.e. as if you were talking to a non-statistician -- we can better translate from plain words to statistical framing)
